# How to query in RQL for special characters like $ in the property path expression like $type

Tags: ravendb-studio

In a ravendb-studio I like to use a RQL-query to query for documents where an property $type has some value.

I tried something like

```
from EventLogEntries where $type in ("...", "...")
```

But it throws an error, that it can't parse the where clause. Any one a suggestion how to correct the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is possible to put the property within qoutes

```
from EventLogEntries where '$type' in ("...", "...")
```

returns the expected results